# PCAP file packets time disarray

Tags: c#, .net, packet, pcap

I have `PCAP file` that the times is in disarray order, if i filter all the packets via `Time column` i can see that the packets number is in disarray order for example it should be packet `1, 2, 3, 4, 5...`
but in my case i have `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 44,...`

Is there a possibility to fix the file and all the packets will appear in chronological order ?

Comment: IP for example does not guarantee packet order

Comment: You list "C#" and ".NET" - is that because you've written a C# program that captures packets and writes them to a file, and the packets are not being written to the file sorted by the time stamp?  Or is it because somebody *else* has a capture file like that, which you're trying to read with a C# program?

Comment: The second options, i have file that i want to read and send all the packets inside this file using PcapDotNet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I infer from "the Time column" that you have Wireshark installed.  Newer versions of Wireshark include a command-line program named `reordercap`, which reads a capture file, sorts the packets by time stamp, and writes out a new file.  Use that on the file, and then read the new file.